# Date format conversion in unix

Tags: unix

Can some one help me convert

2012.02.02D14:32:42.438865000

to

2012-02-02 14:32:42 -0000

in unix.

Comment: In what language?  What have you tried?

Comment: Are you trying to do it through a bash script or string manipulation commands? If so I have a link that might help.

Answer (score 1):

If your trying to do it through a string manipulation command, check this link.
http://unstableme.blogspot.com/2008/07/convert-date-format-using-sed-awk-perl.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the `-0000` is supposed to come from, but this command:

```
echo "2012.02.02D14:32:42.438865000" | tr .D "- " | sed 's/-[[:digit:]]\{1,\}$//'
```

Yields this output:

```
2012-02-02 14:32:42
```